# Translation of time to keyframe animation percentages

Tags: javascript, html, css, css-animations

I'm working on an animation and I'm trying to understand how keyframes fit into it.

I want to show an element for 3 seconds, fade out for 1 second, wait for 3 seconds, fade in for 1 second, be visible for 3 seconds. So a total of 8 seconds (3 + 1 + 3 + 1).

I don't know how to write that as keyframes. I have alternate set in my animation since it's using percentages. Here is what I have so far:

```js
time = 0;
window.addEventListener("load", function() {
   setInterval(function() {
    var label = document.getElementById("label");
    
    if (time==0) {
      label.innerHTML = ++time;
    }
    else {
      label.innerHTML = ++time;
    }
    if (time>=8) time = 0;
    
   }, 1000);
})
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
    font-family:sans-serif;
 }
 #Icons_A0 {
  position: absolute;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  border: 1px solid #A1A1A1;
  background: #E5E5E5;
  width: 234px;
  height: 238px;
  background-color: rgba(255,255,255,1);
  overflow: hidden;
  opacity: 1;
 }
 #Rectangle_175 {
  opacity: 1;
  fill: rgba(75,134,193,1);
  stroke: rgb(84, 75, 193);
  stroke-width: 4px;
  stroke-linejoin: miter;
  stroke-linecap: butt;
  stroke-miterlimit: 4;
  shape-rendering: auto;
 }
 .Rectangle_175 {
  position: absolute;
  overflow: visible;
  width: 134.35028076171875px;
  height: 134.3502655029297px;
  left: 49.825px;
  top: 76.825px;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  transform-origin: left;
 }
 #Ellipse_49 {
  opacity: 1;
  fill: rgba(180,180,180,1);
  stroke: rgb(112, 112, 112);
  stroke-width: 1px;
  stroke-linejoin: miter;
  stroke-linecap: butt;
  stroke-miterlimit: 4;
  shape-rendering: auto;
 }
 .Ellipse_49 {
  position: absolute;
  overflow: visible;
  width: 56px;
  height: 56px;
  left: 72px;
  top: 51px;
    animation: fadein 8s linear 0s infinite alternate;
 }
 @keyframes fadein {
 
  0% {
   opacity: 1;
  }
  20% {
   opacity: 1;
  }
  30% {
   opacity: 0;
  }
  60% {
   opacity: 0;
  }
  70% {
   opacity: 1;
  }
  100% {
   opacity: 1;
  }
 
 }
```

```html
<div id="Icons_A0">
 <svg data-name="Rectangle 175" data-type="Rectangle" class="Rectangle_175">
  <rect id="Rectangle_175" rx="0" ry="0" x="0" y="0" width="120" height="70">
  </rect>
 </svg>
 <svg class="Ellipse_49">
  <ellipse id="Ellipse_49" rx="28" ry="28" cx="28" cy="28">
  </ellipse>
 </svg>
  <span id="label"></span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, then this can be achieved via the following key frame set:

```
@keyframes fadein {
  0% {
    opacity: 1;

  }
  37.5% {
    /* 3 / 8 */
    opacity: 1; 
  }
  50% {
    /* (3 + 1) / 8 */
    opacity: 0.0; 
  }
  87.5% {
    /* (3 + 1 + 3) / 8 */
    opacity: 0.0; 
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1; 
  }
}
```

The comments show how the percentages for different key frames are calculated based on your requirements. The other key change to make is to remove the `alternate` behaviour from your animation rule, to ensure the animation cycle repeats in a consistent fashion as required:

```
/* remove alternate */
animation: fadein 8s linear 0s infinite;
```

Here's a stripped down copy of your code to isolate the animated circle:

```js
function animationListener(event) {
  var type = event.type;
  var label = type;
  
  if (type=="animationiteration") {
    if (app.interval!=null) {
      clearInterval(app.interval);
    }
    app.time = 0;
    app.startTime = new Date().getTime();
    app.interval = setInterval(intervalFunction, 1000);
    intervalFunction();
    label = "iteration";
  }
  else if (type=="animationstart") {
    label = "start";
  }
  else if (type=="animationend") {
    label = "end";
  }
  
  app.stateLabel.innerHTML = label;
}

function intervalFunction() {
  var time = new Date().getTime();
  app.timeLabel.innerHTML = Math.round((time - app.startTime)/1000);
  app.keyframeLabel.innerHTML = window.getComputedStyle(app.ellipse).content;
}

function loadHandler() {
  app.ellipse = document.getElementById("Ellipse_49").parentNode;
  app.stateLabel = document.getElementById("stateLabel");
  app.timeLabel = document.getElementById("timeLabel");
  app.keyframeLabel = document.getElementById("keyframeLabel");
  
  app.ellipse.addEventListener("animationiteration", animationListener);
  app.ellipse.addEventListener("animationend", animationListener);
  app.ellipse.addEventListener("animationstart", animationListener);
}

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", loadHandler);
var app = {};
```

```css
* {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 11px;
  letter-spacing: .6px;
}

#Ellipse_49 {
  opacity: 1;
  fill: rgba(180, 180, 180, 1);
  stroke: rgb(112, 112, 112);
  stroke-width: 1px;
  stroke-linejoin: miter;
  stroke-linecap: butt;
  stroke-miterlimit: 4;
  shape-rendering: auto;
}

.Ellipse_49 {
  position: absolute;
  overflow: visible;
  width: 56px;
  height: 56px;
  left: 72px;
  top: 51px;
  
  /* remove alternate */
  animation: fadein 8s linear 0s infinite;
}

#container {
   top: 130px;
   left: 10px;
   position: relative;
   display: block;
   align-items: center;
   
}

label {
  width: 80px;
  display: inline-block;
}

@keyframes fadein {
  0% {
    opacity: 1;
    content: "show";
  }
  37.5% {
    /* 3 / 8 */
    opacity: 1;
    content: "fade out";
  }
  50% {
    /* (3 + 1) / 8 */
    opacity: 0.0;
    content: "wait";
  }
  87.5% {
    /* (3 + 1 + 3) / 8 */
    opacity: 0.0;
    content: "fade in";
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
    content: "show";
  }
}
```

```html
<svg class="Ellipse_49">
  <ellipse id="Ellipse_49" rx="28" ry="28" cx="28" cy="28">
  </ellipse>
</svg>


<div id="container">
  <label>time: </label>
  <span id="timeLabel"></span>
  <br>
  <label>state: </label>
  <span id="stateLabel"></span>
  <br>
  <label>key frame: </label>
  <span id="keyframeLabel"></span>
</div>
```

Comment: I've added animation state, animation play time and animation keyframe info to your example. The time seems to coincide with the events but the computed animation key frame seems to indicate an upcoming event to occur in 1 second. Also, it starts after the first iteration. Note: I found an example of using the content to store keyframe notes here jsfiddle.net/z4ytsesh. Feel free to update it.

Answer (score 1):

If your total length is 8s, and you just need to translate that to percentages the math is pretty simple:
100/8=12.5

So, your keyframes would come in at:

```
1 sec : 12.5 * 1 = 12.5%
4 sec : 12.5 * 4 = 50%
7 sec : 12.5 * 7 = 87.5%
8 sec : 12.5 * 8 = 100%
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding @DacreDenny's answer here so I can modify it and add notes.

```js
function animationListener(event) {
  var type = event.type;
  var label = type;
  
  if (type=="animationiteration") {
    if (app.interval!=null) {
      clearInterval(app.interval);
    }
    app.time = 0;
    app.startTime = new Date().getTime();
    app.interval = setInterval(intervalFunction, 15);
    intervalFunction();
    label = "iteration";
  }
  else if (type=="animationstart") {
    label = "start";
  }
  else if (type=="animationend") {
    label = "end";
  }
  
  app.stateLabel.innerHTML = label;
}

function intervalFunction() {
  var currentTime = new Date().getTime();
  var time = (currentTime - app.startTime)/1000;
  var duration = parseFloat(window.getComputedStyle(app.ellipse).animationDuration);
  var maxValue = 100;
  var position = ((time * maxValue)/duration);
  
  app.timeLabel.innerHTML = Math.round(time);
  app.keyframeLabel.innerHTML = window.getComputedStyle(app.ellipse).content;
  app.timelineRange.value = position;
  app.positionLabel.innerHTML = Math.round(position) + "%";
}

function loadHandler() {
  app.ellipse = document.getElementById("Ellipse_49").parentNode;
  app.stateLabel = document.getElementById("stateLabel");
  app.timeLabel = document.getElementById("timeLabel");
  app.keyframeLabel = document.getElementById("keyframeLabel");
  app.timelineRange = document.getElementById("timelineRange");
  app.positionLabel = document.getElementById("positionLabel");
  
  app.ellipse.addEventListener("animationiteration", animationListener);
  app.ellipse.addEventListener("animationend", animationListener);
  app.ellipse.addEventListener("animationstart", animationListener);
}

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", loadHandler);
var app = {};
```

```css
* {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 11px;
  letter-spacing: .6px;
}

@keyframes fadein {
  0% {
    opacity: 1;
    content: "show";
  }
  37.5% {
    /* 3 / 8 */
    opacity: 1;
    content: "fade out";
  }
  50% {
    /* (3 + 1) / 8 */
    opacity: 0.0;
    content: "wait";
  }
  87.5% {
    /* (3 + 1 + 3) / 8 */
    opacity: 0.0;
    content: "fade in";
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
    content: "show";
  }
}

#Ellipse_49 {
  opacity: 1;
  fill: rgba(180, 180, 180, 1);
  stroke: rgb(112, 112, 112);
  stroke-width: 1px;
  stroke-linejoin: miter;
  stroke-linecap: butt;
  stroke-miterlimit: 4;
  shape-rendering: auto;
}

.Ellipse_49 {
  position: absolute;
  overflow: visible;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  left: 20px;
  top: 50px;
  
  /* remove alternate */
  animation: fadein 4s linear 0s infinite;
}

#container {
   top: 130px;
   left: 10px;
   position: relative;
   display: block;
}

label {
  width: 80px;
  display: inline-block;
}

input[type=range] {
  outline: 0px solid red;
  display: block;
  width: 90%;
  margin-left: 0;
}
input[type=range]::-webkit-slider-runnable-track {
  width: 100%;
  height: 8.4px;
  cursor: pointer;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px #000000, 0px 0px 0px #0d0d0d;
  background: rgb(255,255,255);
}
```

```html
<svg class="Ellipse_49">
  <ellipse id="Ellipse_49" rx="28" ry="28" cx="28" cy="28">
  </ellipse>
</svg>


<div id="container">
  <input id="timelineRange" type="range" value="0" min="0" max="100">
  <br>
  
  <label>time: </label>
  <span id="timeLabel"></span>
  <br>
  <label>position: </label>
  <span id="positionLabel"></span>
  <br>
  <label>state: </label>
  <span id="stateLabel"></span>
  <br>
  <label>key frame: </label>
  <span id="keyframeLabel"></span>
  <br>
  <br>
</div>
```